# hosting react app and express server cpanel

Tags: node.js, web-deployment

I am new to hosting and it would be of immense help to me if somebody can explain in very detail.

I have following questions:

1. I have front end using `react app` and backend using `expressjs` and `mysql`. i have a working simple application in my computer . I start backend and front end using local host and they work perfect . when I bought hosting which supports `nodejs` , I don't know where to place the front end file and backend file .
2. `npm run build` - > builds a react app . in cpanel - file manager , which file I should place in public html . front end code or backend express code
3. I placed html code in public_html but how to start interacting with server.
4. When I used fetch("http://lcoalhost:30000") to fetch I couldn't get the app.get("/",(req ,resp)) working ..

I am really confused . if somebody can explain in detail how to start uploading both the react and express file and the location to place these files.

Comment: Did you mean to spell it "lcoalhost:30000"?  Show your server code explicitly.

Comment: its typo error while asking....

Answer (score 0):

1. Upload your react app build files inside public_html. Don't forget to change the localhost url to your express app to your actual url.
2. Create a folder outside public_html and upload your express app in it.
3. Create a nodejs app (using cPanel, if it has). Use the express folder and a url different from home (like /api) during creation.