# How to deploy React App client and Node Server to cPanel

Tags: node.js, reactjs, deployment, cpanel

I am trying to deploy a react app and a node server to my domain http://cv-devlabs.com/ with cPanel but failing to run. Most of the time I'm getting a "server responded with the 404 error".

I have tried methods from "[hosting react app and express server cpanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56739850/hosting-react-app-and-express-server-cpanel)" and "[How to deploy a react app on cPanel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49939601/how-to-deploy-a-react-app-on-cpanel)" and failed at both. I'm assuming I did something wrong here.

My file structure is:

Root-Folder--
-client
--build
--node_modules
--public
--package.json(client)(content added below)
-.gitignore
-package.json(server)(content added below)
-procfile
-server.js

Package.json (client)

```
    "name": "client",
  "homepage": "http://cv-devlabs.com/vidci-vid2/",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8000",
```

Package.json(server)

```
{
  "name": "vidci-vid",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "socket.io": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "PROD=true node server.js",
    "postinstall": "cd ./client && yarn"
  }
}
```

This is working fine on Heroku but on cPanel, it's not. The whole project can be found at https://github.com/ConsultVerraton/vidci-vid.git

Thanks to anyone who can help and thanks to anyone who can try. Do let me know if more information is needed.

Thanks

Comment: Hey man. Could you deploy MERN app on cpanel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot host a `node.js` app in most providers working with cpanel. If you want to host a node.js app you should deploy it on a vps. You can follow this tutorial for example:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04

But in these cpanel providers, you could host a static react app (for example an app build with create-react-app). This kind of app does not need `node.js` at **runtime**. So you can build the assets and push them to your cpanel host.

You can follow this tutorial:
https://dev.to/crishanks/deploy-host-your-react-app-with-cpanel-in-under-5-minutes-4mf6

Comment: I am using a VPS on CentOS 7.. I'll give the tutorial a shot and update here shortly

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but it depend if the host provider allow it.

I'm actually running a express server on a cPanel account.

I didn't found the official documentation of cPanel but this is a pretty good one: [How to create a Node.js application with cPanel using the Node.js Selector](https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/cpanel/cpanel-software/create-application-with-nodejs-selector)

If your looking to do it in command line, this the official documentation from cPanel :[How to Install a Node.js Application](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/How+to+Install+a+Node.js+Application).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about react but for anyone who wants to know how to deploy node js app to Cpanel this is a good source for him, this explains thoroughly how to deploy node js app to cpanel please check [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O3Tkpy_lVAA)